# Python importing a specific library only works under home directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

The python interpreter I was using is located to '~/miniconda2/bin/python',2.7.11.

The problem is as follows:
If the current directory is home directory, I start the python in command line and import skimage.filters library. It works perfectly.

```
Name:~ Name $ python
>>> import skimage.filters
>>>
```

But when I tried to cd to another directory and did the same thing. I would get a importError as follows:

```
Name:~ Name $ cd dir/
Name: dir Name $ python
>>> import skimage.filters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/filters/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .lpi_filter import inverse, wiener, LPIFilter2D
  File "/Users/Name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/filters/lpi_filter.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.fftpack import ifftshift
  File "/Users/Name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "/Users/Name/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import _fftpack
ImportError: cannot import name _fftpack
>>>
```

It's really odd because the paths of the python interpreter and the `sys.path` of them are the same. I also tried `os.chdir('home directory')` to make sure the `os.getcwd()` of both are the same as well. I tried to update the libraries and reinstall them. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Please set up a conda environment and try again, it may solve your problem.

Comment: Just found that the conda executable is missing the binary folder.

Comment: Wow, it works after I reinstalled MiniConda. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by reinstalling Python.